# How to fix Object reference not set to an instance of an object MySql Connection Issue

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I'm creating a Application that's utilizing mysql as a database, however, when I run the program I keep getting this error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

On line 29 in the `private class registerUser()` where it begins as `String connString =....` is where the problem is how dow I fix it?

```
private void registerUser()
{
    String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsDBConnString"].ToString();

    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    queryStr = "";

    queryStr = "INSERT INTO sportsdbmlb.userregistration (firstname, middlename, lastname, email, username, password )" +
        "VALUES('"+firstnameTextBox.Text + "','"+ middlenameTextBox.Text +"','" + lastnameTextBox.Text + "','" + emailTextBox.Text +
        "','" + usernameTextBox.Text + "','" + passwordTextBox.Text + "')";

    cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

    cmd.ExecuteReader();

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is your App.config?

Comment: Here is my Web Config.     <connectionStrings>
   <add name="SportsDBConString"
        connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;User ID=sportsdbappuser;Password=sportsdbappuser2014;Database=sportsdbmlb;"
       providerName="MySql.Data.MySql.Client"/>
 </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have a connectionString in your App.config or your Web.config.

If you want to fix your issue you should at least do no 1:

1. add that configuration
2. you can also add a null check on the setting. In this case if it's coming from your App.config/Web.config and if you add it now, it will probably never miss anymore.

Add the configuration in App.config/Web.config depending on whether you build a console application or a web application:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="SportsDBConnString" providerName="System.Data.YourProviderName" 
           connectionString="Valid Connection String;" />
    </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

Add a null check:

```
if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsDBConnString"] != null) {
    String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsDBConnString"].ConnectionString;
    //Do other logic here or move connString declaration outside this if

}
else {
    throw new Exception("Missing ConnectionString SportsDBConnString in App.config/Web.Config");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConnectionString` property.

```
String connString = System.Configuration
                          .ConfigurationManager
                          .ConnectionStrings["SportsDBConnString"]
                          .ConnectionString;
```